# How to have user inputs tracked within a list? And how to display the individual elements that were tracked?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

So I'm pretty much a newbie at coding in python. We have a problem that we were asked to solve, so my problem is whenever I input a value and the while loop ends the lastest input is the only one that gets displayed. Additionally I try to set a limit on the number of inputs however what my code prints out is more than what I set for example the limit = 2 however the values printed will be 8? How do I solve this? Thanks!

p.s yes i'm trying to represent it within a table

This is my code for example!

```
amongus = []

entries = 2

while entries > 0: # We will decrement max_tries on each loop
  #User Inputs
  if entries==0:
   break
  mat1 = input ("Input the Book Name: ")
  amongus.append(mat1)  
  mat2 = input ("Input the Author: ")
  amongus.append(mat2)  
  mat3 = input("Input the Dewey Decimal Number: ")
  amongus.append(mat3)  
  mat4 = input ("Input the Book Shelf Number: ")
  amongus.append(mat4)
  entries -= 1


     


#Printing Details 
  
print("| Title"," "*25,"| Author"," "*8,"| Dewey Decimal","  | Bookshelf"," ")
print("-"*82)
  
for element in amongus:
      print("|",mat1," "*(55-len(mat1)),"|",mat2," "*(60- 
      len(mat2)),"|",mat3," "* (17-len(str(mat3))),"|",mat4," "*(10-len(mat4)))
      print("-"*82)
```

Answer (score 0):

for every entry, you are appending four elements. `mat1`-`mat4`. Thats why the total number of elements is 2*4=8.

Also, your variables `mat1`-`mat4` hold the values of the last input.
Since you are saving every value in your list `amongus`, you should iterate over `amongus` with a step of four. you can do that with

```
for i in range(0, len(amongus), 4):
```

to access the values in your list by index i, you can use `amongus[i]`.
So, to select the second value you can use i+1, for the third i+2 and so on.

Your code could look like this which prints the desired output:

```
for i in range(0, len(amongus), 4):
    print("|", amongus[i], " " * (55 - len(amongus[i])), "|", 
          amongus[i+1], " " * (60 - len(amongus[i+1])), "|",
          amongus[i+2], " " * (17 - len(str(amongus[i+2]))), "|",
          amongus[i+3], " " * (10 - len(amongus[i+3])))
    print("-" * 82)
```

I am also not sure about your calculations with for example `55-len()`, but you know your data better and be able to adjust if necessary.
Hope that helps.